# What is the term for this pruning technique that causes stubby, clublike branches?

Tags: trees, pruning, growth, technique, terminology

These [Platanus × acerifolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus_%C3%97_acerifolia) trees (London Planetree) were pruned to have this short, stubby branch structure. What is this called, and how is is done?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is called [pollarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollarding). It is a pruning system that promotes uniform yearly growth, in dense heads over the tree. You basically cut the branch ends at a certain diameter, and remove all smaller growth. Then on a yearly to almost a 20 year  basis, remove the shoots that form, at the base. the result is the formation of these clublike heads, which grow in diameter, and a smaller mature tree.

When left alone, these trees can revert back to normal growth, but the branch structure will always look peculiar in the areas where the pollarding had been performed.

This pruning method is only suitable for certain species, and the most common of these are the *Platanus* (Sycamore) species.

Examples of trees that do well as pollards include the following:

- [beeches (*Fagus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beech)
- [oaks (*Quercus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak)
- [maples (*Acer*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple)
- [black locust (*Robinia*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinia)
- [hornbeams (*Carpinus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hornbeam)
- [lindens (*Tilia*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilia)
- [planes (*Platanus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus)
- [horse chestnuts (*Aesculus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesculus)
- [mulberries (*Morus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morus_(plant))
- [redbud (*Cercis*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercis)
- [tree of heaven (*Ailanthus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ailanthus)
- [willows (*Salix*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willow)
- [hazelnut (*Corylus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazel)
- [ash (*Fraxinus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraxinus)
- [chestnut (*Castanea*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chestnut)
- [elm (*Ulmus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elm)
- [poplar (*Populus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus)
- [birch (*Betula*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch)
- [privet (*Ligustrum*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privet)
- [juniper (*Juniperus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniper)
- [dogwood (*Cornus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_(genus))
- [crabapple (*Malus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malus)
- [wild plum (*Prunus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus)
- [sumac (*Rhus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumac)
- [holly (*Ilex*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holly)
- [spurge (*Eucalyptus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus)
- [laurel (*Laurus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurus)
- [cotoneaster (*Cotoneaster*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotoneaster)
- [broom (*Cytisus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytisus)
- [yews (*Taxus*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxus)
- [honeysuckle (*Lonicera*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeysuckle)
- [clematis (*Clematis*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clematis)
- [wisteria (*Wisteria*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisteria)

Comment: The more extreme form of trimming, where you cut at the base of trunk is called **Coppicing**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppicing

Comment: This type of pruning is severe and requires a lot of energy.  You end up with a bush on the end of a stick.  Try not to use this for your landscape unless you will have time/money to continue this amputation.  Once you start, the natural form of the tree/shrub is hard or impossible to retrieve.